# Laravel5: How to access paginated data before passing it to blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, pagination, pluck

I fetch some data with

```
$merchants = Merchant::selectRaw($query)->with(...)->whereHas(...)->where(...)->paginate(10);
```

Now, I want to `pluck()` this data **before** passing it to blade. This doesn't work:

```
$collection = collect($merchants);
```

When I fetch the data with

```
$merchants = Merchant::selectRaw($query)->with(...)->whereHas(...)->where(...)->get();
```

I can use `$collection = collect($merchants);` without any problemns, but pagination does not work for sure.

So, how can I combine `paginate()` with `collect()` or rahter access paginated data in the controller before passing it to blade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the collection using

```
$collection = $merchants->getCollection();
```

or get data as an array using

```
$array = $merchants->items();
```

Comment: Piu, so easy ;-) I just found out, that I can also use `$merchants->pluck('id')` to achieve what I need... Thx!

Comment: @Dong3000 Yes. you can do that.